# Angular 2 view not updates on array change

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an array of objects with properties `name` and `age`. Name of the array is `person`.

Problem is when i update the property of an element of array as :

`this.person[0].name = "godfather";`

original array is updated but component view remains as it is. I figured out the problem is angular change detection doesn't consider updation inside an array as a change. So, i tried below statement (changes reference to array):

```
this.person = this.person.slice();
```

I just want to know, Is using the later statement a good practice or there is some better approach to deal with the above problem?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5sa3pe. What should I change to replicate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the cost of this `slice()` operation. If it's for small arrays it might not cause any harm but if it is for large arrays it may cause notable performance issues. In this case using an observable that notifies the receiver actively about changes is a better way.

Comment: What would be a better solution?

Comment: An observable or using `IterableDiffer` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14ee75924b6ae770115f7f260d720efa8bfb576a/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_for.ts#L111, perhaps others. Depends on the concrete use case.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5sa3pe. What should I change to replicate it

Comment: Another one where I am passing array of objects to child component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqvpsd

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added a question as well to elaborate my concern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200638/make-view-not-to-update-on-change-in-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is an unspecified use of `slice` that may work with some but not all JS implementations.
I have used this with success:

```
this.person = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.person));
```

Comment: This seems rather expensive in compairson. Do you you have a link that provides more information about where `slice()` might not work?

Comment: The JSON approach is more expensive, yes. However, if it's only used in UI and not in loops or otherwise time-critical code I don't see a problem. According to the specification slice needs at least one parameter. Calling it with no parameter is not specified.

Comment: Just `slice(0)` would do then I guess as well?

Comment: I haven't tried it but yes that should work and would be less expensive. The JSON approach I have tried and it works.

Comment: Also, slice only performs a shallow copy. If the array contains objects slice won't work for this purpose. In fact, if I understand the OP correctly, it is an array of objects and that's why it won't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I think a shallow copy is fine because it is the fastest way to get a new (different) instance of the array with the same content, just enough to make Angular2 change detection aware of the change.