# Make view NOT to update on change in array of objects

Tags: angular

I have seen a dozen of SO posts like **[THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658843/angular-2-view-not-updates-on-array-change)** where people claim that the view rendering array of objects using `*ngFor` directive is not updating if any object value changes.

I am trying to replicate the same scenario and then want to test out concepts like `KeyValueDiffers` and the not so efficient `slice` method to forcefully invoke change detection.

I know that we can do it by using `trackBy` in `*ngFor` directive or by setting `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush` but these would be forcefully not invoking change detection.

Can I force this behavior just by having a complex data structure where I change a nested property and the view doesn't update

For [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqvpsd), I have created a component having array of objects which is passed as `Input()` property to the child component as a whole and as individual items inside `*ngFor`. I have written a service which tries to updated a value inside the array and the view gets updated. I don't want that.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Chellappan as mentioned, I want to test out KeyValueDiffers and would also want to know the scenarios where this can happen so that I try to avoid them beforehand in the actual implementation